# not able to restore data after app is killed ios

Tags: ios

I've to save few text field contents and restore them even after the app is killed.

I'm saving it using -

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.viewController saveUserData];
}

and restoring it using -

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.viewController restoreUserData];
}

- (void)saveUserData {
   //save 
}

- (void)restoreUserData {
   //restore
}
```

I don't see it when app is killed and opened again, am i missing anything, please help.

Comment: Do you have a `ViewController` on the screen that you're trying to get data from?  When you call `[ViewController alloc]` you are creating a new instance where all the properties of `self` are `nil`.  You are not saving actual values, and when you restore, you aren't restoring to the screen.

Comment: [saveUserData saveUserData]; what is this?

Comment: @BrianNickel yes I've viewcontroller, is creating an instance of that view problem? if that's not the correct way how to call method in viewcontroller

Comment: The same way you would in any object oriented language, with a reference to the actual instance.  You really should pick up a book on Objective-C as well before trying to dive into more complex stuff.

Comment: @BrianNickel , thank you, I understood what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just calling

```
ViewController *restore = [ViewController alloc];
[restore restoreUserData];
```

isn't enough to set up the ViewController. You'd have to `init` it too.

```
ViewController *restore = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[restore restoreUserData];
```

But I suspect that what you really want isn't to create a new view controller, but to save the data from one that's already in existence. In that case, you'll need to keep an instance variable or property for the view controller.